# Making a proxy for unix using C socket

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, telnet

I am trying to create two proxies that connect two different virtual machines together. They should connect like this

> vm1(telnet) <--> proxy1 <--> proxy2 <--> vm2(telnet daemon)

The user would open up vm1 and vm2 then another instance of vm1. On vm1 you would run proxy1, on vm2 run proxy2 then on the second vm1 connect to the proxy1 via telnet.

Once the user is connected to proxy1 via vm1, proxy1 should then connect to proxy2. Proxy2 will send what vm2 has displayed which is a prompt to login. It will send that to proxy1 then to vm1. The user should be able to type into vm1 and send each line to proxy1 then proxy2 then vm2 as if they were at vm2 all along. Instead I am given a couple words from the vm2's login page but it is mostly random chars and some of the tv static chars. It keeps sending me massive amounts of random chars until I close everything down.

Here is my code (cproxy.c is proxy1 and sproxy.c is proxy2)

cproxy.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define MAX_PENDING 5
#define MAX_LINE 1024

struct sockaddr_in LocalTelnetAddress;
struct sockaddr_in SproxyAddress;
struct hostent *hp;
struct timeval tv;

int setUpTelnetConnection(int port){
    bzero((char *)&LocalTelnetAddress, sizeof(LocalTelnetAddress));
    LocalTelnetAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    LocalTelnetAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    LocalTelnetAddress.sin_port = htons(port); // Change 5200

    // Create socket.
    int localTelnetSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (localTelnetSocket < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: c telnet socket.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Bind socket.
    if (bind(localTelnetSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &LocalTelnetAddress, sizeof(LocalTelnetAddress)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: c telnet bind.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return localTelnetSocket;
}

int setUpSproxyConnection(char *host, int port)
{
    hp = gethostbyname(host);
    bzero((char *)&SproxyAddress, sizeof(SproxyAddress));
    SproxyAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy(hp->h_addr, (char *)&SproxyAddress.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
    SproxyAddress.sin_port = htons(port);  //change 6200


    // Create the socket.
    int sproxySocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sproxySocket < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: sproxy socket.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return sproxySocket;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    fd_set readfds;
    int rv;
    int n, len = 0;
    struct timeval tv;

    char buf1[MAX_LINE];
    socklen_t len1;
    char buf2[MAX_LINE];

    int port1;
    int port2;
    int localTelnetSocket;
    int sproxySocket;
    if(argc == 4){
        port1 = atoi(argv[1]);
        port2 = atoi(argv[3]);
        localTelnetSocket = setUpTelnetConnection(port1);
        sproxySocket = setUpSproxyConnection(argv[2],port2);
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stderr, "illegal argc\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    listen(localTelnetSocket, MAX_PENDING);
  //  int len = sizeof(LocalTelnetAddress);
    // Connect local telnet
    int localTelnet_s = accept(localTelnetSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&LocalTelnetAddress, &len1);
    if (localTelnet_s < 0) {
        perror("simplex-talk: accept");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Connect sproxy
    int sproxy_s = connect(sproxySocket, (struct sockaddr *) &SproxyAddress, sizeof(SproxyAddress));
    if (sproxy_s < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR connecting to sproxy.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(1){
        // clear the set ahead of time
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);

        // add our descriptors to the set
        FD_SET(localTelnet_s, &readfds);
        FD_SET(sproxySocket, &readfds);

        // find the largest descriptor, and plus one.

        if (localTelnet_s > sproxySocket) n = localTelnet_s + 1;
        else n = sproxySocket +1;


        // wait until either socket has data ready to be recv()d (timeout 10.5 secs)
        tv.tv_sec = 10;
        tv.tv_usec = 500000;

        rv = select(n, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);


        if (rv == -1) {
            perror("select"); // error occurred in select()
        } else if (rv == 0) {
            printf("Timeout occurred!  No data after 10.5 seconds.\n");
        } else {
            // one or both of the descriptors have data
            if (FD_ISSET(localTelnet_s, &readfds)) {
                memset(buf1,0,strlen(buf1));
                len = recv(localTelnet_s, buf1, sizeof(buf1), 0);
                send(sproxySocket, buf1, sizeof(buf1), 0);
               // printf("%s", buf1);
            }
            if (FD_ISSET(sproxySocket, &readfds)) {
                memset(buf2,0,strlen(buf2));
                len = recv(sproxySocket, buf2, sizeof(buf2), 0);
                send(localTelnet_s, buf2, sizeof(buf2), 0);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

sproxy.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define MAX_PENDING 5
#define MAX_LINE 1024

struct sockaddr_in TelnetDaemonAddress;
struct sockaddr_in CproxyAddress;
struct hostent *hp;
char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
//struct hostent *hp;
struct timeval tv;

int setUpCproxyConnection(int port)
{
    bzero((char *)&CproxyAddress, sizeof(CproxyAddress));
    CproxyAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    CproxyAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    CproxyAddress.sin_port = htons(port);

    // Create  socket.
    int cproxySocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (cproxySocket < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: cproxy socket.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Bind socket
    if (bind(cproxySocket, (struct sockaddr *) &CproxyAddress, sizeof(CproxyAddress)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: cproxy bind.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return cproxySocket;
}

int setUpTelnetDaemonConnection()
{
    hp = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");
    bzero((char *)&TelnetDaemonAddress, sizeof(TelnetDaemonAddress));
    TelnetDaemonAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy(hp->h_addr, (char *)&TelnetDaemonAddress.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
    TelnetDaemonAddress.sin_port = htons(23);  //change 6200


    // Create the socket.
    int telnetDaemonSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (telnetDaemonSocket < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: telnetDaemonSocket.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return telnetDaemonSocket;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    fd_set readfds;
    int rv;
    int n, len = 0;
    struct timeval tv;

    char buf1[MAX_LINE];
    socklen_t len1;
    char buf2[MAX_LINE];


    int port;
    int cproxySocket;
    int telnetDaemonSocket;


    if(argc == 2){
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
        cproxySocket = setUpCproxyConnection(port);
        telnetDaemonSocket = setUpTelnetDaemonConnection();
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stderr, "illegal argc\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Connect cproxy
    listen(cproxySocket, MAX_PENDING);
   // int len = sizeof(CproxyAddress);
    int cproxy_s = accept(cproxySocket, (struct sockaddr *) &CproxyAddress, &len1);


    if (cproxy_s < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: cproxy accept.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Connect telnet daemon
    if (connect(telnetDaemonSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &TelnetDaemonAddress, sizeof(TelnetDaemonAddress)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: telnet daemon connect.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(1){
        // clear the set ahead of time
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);

        // add our descriptors to the set
        FD_SET(cproxy_s, &readfds);
        FD_SET(telnetDaemonSocket, &readfds);


        // find the largest descriptor, and plus one.

        if (cproxy_s > telnetDaemonSocket) n = cproxy_s + 1;
        else n = telnetDaemonSocket +1;

        // wait until either socket has data ready to be recv()d (timeout 10.5 secs)
        tv.tv_sec = 10;
        tv.tv_usec = 500000;
        rv = select(n, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

        if (rv == -1) {
            perror("select"); // error occurred in select()
        } else if (rv == 0) {
            printf("Timeout occurred!  No data after 10.5 seconds.\n");
        } else {
            // one or both of the descriptors have data
            if (FD_ISSET(cproxy_s, &readfds)) {
                memset(buf1,0,strlen(buf1));
                len = recv(cproxy_s, buf1, sizeof(buf1), 0);
                send(telnetDaemonSocket, buf1, sizeof(buf1), 0);
            }
            if (FD_ISSET(telnetDaemonSocket, &readfds)) {
                memset(buf2,0,strlen(buf2));
                len = recv(telnetDaemonSocket, buf2, sizeof(buf2), 0);
                send(cproxy_s, buf2, sizeof(buf2), 0);
                //printf("%s", buf2);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Beside the complete lack of error checking that you really want to add, you just want to send as many bytes as you received.

Comment: So besides adding error checking to all relevant system calls, drop these lines `memset( ...`. and replace `send(.., ..., sizeof ..., 0);` by `send(.., ..., len, 0);`.

Comment: Alk, you are the best. It works now. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the complete lack of error checking that you really want to add, you just want to send as many bytes as you received.

So besides adding error checking to all relevant system calls, drop these lines `memset( ....` and replace `send(.., ..., sizeof ..., 0);` by `send(.., ..., len, 0);`.

Answer (score 1):

```
len = recv(localTelnet_s, buf1, sizeof(buf1), 0);
send(sproxySocket, buf1, sizeof(buf1), 0);
```

You are ignoring:

1. End of stream, signalled by `len == 0`.
2. Errors, signalled by `len == -1`.
3. The number of bytes received, signalled by `len` fif it is positive.

It should be more like:

```
len = recv(localTelnet_s, buf1, sizeof(buf1), 0);
if (len == 0)
    // close both sockets and remove them from the FD sets
else if (len == -1)
{
    perror("recv"); // at least
    // close both sockets and remove them from the FD sets
}
else
{
    send(sproxySocket, buf1, len, 0);
}
```